# on button click it updates the second activity spinner and textviews

Tags: java, android, arrays, xml, android-intent

I am creating an app which has 2 activities. Main activity has three buttons with different movie genre. On clicking any of the three buttons it should go to the second activity which consists of:

2 spinners: to display movie name and 1 for movie time
2 textview to display movie rating and casts 
textview to open calendar

the spinners should be updated depending on the movie genre selected as well as the textviews for movie rating and cast

So far i have created the XML for main activity and class to make an arraylist to hold the movie details. I also did intent to go to next page but i am confused on how to display movies in spinner only for selected genre.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to pass something to the next activity:

```
Intent i = new Intent(context,activity2.class);
i.putExtra("genre", mGenre);  
startActivity(i);
```

Then in activity2 on load you can pull the genre:

```
String genre = getintent().getStringExtra("genre");
```

Then you fill the lists based off the genre. You could pass an int as well if you dont feel like dealing with strings.

Answer (score 0):

You should make your movie class `Serializable` in order to pass it to next Activity.
There are different ways to achieve that which I have mentioned two in below:

1. http://www.parcelabler.com/
2. https://github.com/johncarl81/parceler

Then you can pass your `ArrayList` to the second activity.

**FirstActivity**

```
ArrayList<Movie> myMovieList = new ArrayList<>();
...
Intent intent = new Intent(context, secondActivity.class);
i.putExtra("my_movie_list", myMovieList);  
startActivity(i);
```

**SecondActivity**

```
ArrayList<Movie> myMovieList = getintent().getExtra("my_movie_list");
```

**Update** (Extracting specific movies from movie list):

```
        List<Movie> selectedMovieList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0 ; i < movieList.size(); i++ ) {
            if(movieList.get(i).getGenre().equals("selected_genre_name")) {
                selectedMovieList.add(movieList.get(i));
            }
         }
```

Comment: what does the first link do ?

Comment: @akm It generates a `Serializable` data class (model) for you. I personally prefer the second way. Do you have a class or object which refers to movie or genre?

Comment: i created  a class which has the movie details (String genre, String movie_title, Double ratings,String mainCasts,  String[] showTime, Double duration). i add movie details in my second activity

Comment: @akm If I click one first button in first Activity (For example genre A) and go to second Activity, in the second Activity would I have data of all movies or data of movies with genre A?

Comment: just the data for genre A

Comment: @akm As you said **I am confused on how to display movies in spinner only for selected genre**, can you explain what is your question in more detail? because you have data of the selected genre (genre A) and it should be OK.

Comment: i created a list which holds the data for all three genre. Upon clicking the button for genre A it should get values from the list and display in spinner. When a movie is selected from spinner it should update the textviews (movierating,duration and casts & also update the second spinner which is for time)

Comment: @akm So if I understand correctly you want to know that when the user clicks genre A button in first Activity, how you can extract data of genre A (from the list with all data) and send that data to second Activity. Is that right?

Comment: yes thats what i want. When the user clicks button A it should show the movies of genre A in spinner, show the time its being played in the second spinner and also update the textviews which display (movie rating, cast and the duration of movie)

Comment: @ Mostafa Aryannejad  yes thats what want to do.

Comment: @akm First of all you should create a new ArrayList which when the user selects one of the genres, you should fill that list with the movies of that specific genre. The most basic way is to implement a for loop and with an if statement inside it check which movies match the selected genre. Lets name that arrayList **selectedMoviesList**. ok?

Comment: i have created an arraylist which holds all the movies but confused on how to separate it by genre. For that youre saying i need to create a for loop ?

Comment: @akm Yes exactly, I have updated my answer with the loop which is needed. take a look at it.

Comment: @akm After doing this step, you have a list of movies with selected genre. Now you should send this list to next activity. which needs your movie class to be parcelable. which suggest you to use the second link i provided to you.